# Where condition in my query not filtering the records properly

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Where condition in my query not filtering the records properly. I have attached my query and results in the picture. The records must show only the taskNum="88" but additionally it's also showing 89. My need is to get the record where taskNum="88" and Tranlineno=1 or Null. Help me please what's wrong with the query.
[image: My SQLITE QUERY]

Comment: try breaking your query as per your need and use parentheses properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use proper parenthesis to properly format the query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM picktaskdetail 
WHERE taskNum="88" AND (Tranlineno="1" OR wlotno is NULL) AND ITEM = "0101010601BR"
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks @Shivam Pokhriyal

Answer (score 1):

Add proper parenthesis for the condition you write in query.
Your conditions are:-

1. taskNum="88"
2. Tranlineno=1 or Null

Now, this can be Get the result that matches **condition 1** & **condition 2**.
Now your condition 2 is an OR condition so that needs to be handled separately using parenthesis.

See the below-mentioned query implementation:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM picktaskdetail 
WHERE taskNum="88" 
AND (Tranlineno="1" OR wlotno is NULL) 
AND ITEM = "0101010601BR"
```